# how use pac file to HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net

I want use proxy to `HttpWebRequest` but my proxy address is http://cdproxy.anadolu.edu.tr/proxy.pac and I not wanting change my proxy address to http://cdproxy.anadolu.edu.tr.

How can I use this address to my proxy?

```
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
Request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy.Address = new Uri("http://cdproxy.anadolu.edu.tr/proxy.pac");
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
Request.Proxy = myProxy;
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article on CodeProject - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12168/Using-PAC-files-proxy

Basically uses interop with WinHTTP, resolves the proxy using the PAC for a given URL then returns the information to you.